# Pegar valores em comum em varias colunas de um dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho uma tabela com valores numéricos e gostaria de pegar os valores em comum em todas colunas (interseção) e os valores únicos de cada uma utilizando pandas (Python).

```
    Position_a  Position_b  Position_c  Position_d  Position_e  Position_f
0   45794939.0  45794939.0  45794939    45794939.0  45794939    45794939.0
1   45794975.0  45794975.0  45794975    45794975.0  45794975    45794975.0
2   45794983.0  45794983.0  45794983    45794983.0  45794983    45794983.0
3   45794988.0  45794988.0  45794988    45794988.0  45794988    45794988.0
4   45795006.0  45795006.0  45795006    45795006.0  45795006    45795006.0
```

Comment: Olá Leandro, bem vindo ao StackOverflow em português, teria como você traduzir sua pergunta?  Se possivel faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow/tour) para conhecer melhor o site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu exemplo está um pouco estranho, uma vez que todos as linhas estão presentes em todas as colunas, mas talvez o seguinte método para contar as ocorrências te ajude.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    data = {'Position_a': [45794975, 45794983, 45794988, 45795006, np.NaN],
            'Position_b': [45794939, 45794975, 45794983, 45794988, 45795006],
            'Position_c': [45794939, 45794975, 45794983, 45794988, 45795006],
            'Position_d': [45794939, 45794975, 45794983, 45794988,np.NaN],
            'Position_e': [45794939, 45794975, 45794983, 45795006, np.NaN],
            'Position_f': [45794939, 45794975, 45794983, 45794988, 45795006]
            }

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

    print(df)

    tidydf = pd.melt(df)

    tidydf.pivot_table(index = ['value'], columns = ['variable'], aggfunc = len, fill_value = 0)
```